# Cannot listen for a key that isn't associated with a Redux Store - React Navigtion

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I just upgraded my React Navigation to version 1.0.0. They have new ways to integrate the navigation and Redux. Here's my code

configureStore.js

```
export default (rootReducer, rootSaga) => {


const middleware = []
const enhancers = []

/* ------------- Analytics Middleware ------------- */
middleware.push(ScreenTracking)

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware({ sagaMonitor })
middleware.push(sagaMiddleware)

const navMiddleware = createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware('root', state => state.nav)
middleware.push(navMiddleware)

/* ------------- Assemble Middleware ------------- */

enhancers.push(applyMiddleware(...middleware))

/* ------------- AutoRehydrate Enhancer ------------- */

// add the autoRehydrate enhancer
if (ReduxPersist.active) {
  enhancers.push(autoRehydrate())
}

const store = createAppropriateStore(rootReducer, compose(...enhancers))

// kick off root saga
sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga)

return store
}
```

ReduxNavigation.js

```
const addListener = createReduxBoundAddListener('root')

// here is our redux-aware our smart component
function ReduxNavigation (props) {
  const { dispatch, nav } = props
  const navigation = ReactNavigation.addNavigationHelpers({
    dispatch,
    state: nav,
    uriPrefix: prefix,
    addListener
 })
 return <AppNavigation navigation={navigation} />
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({ nav: state.nav })
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ReduxNavigation)
```

ReduxIndex.js

```
export default () => {
  /* ------------- Assemble The Reducers ------------- */
  const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    //few reducers
  })

  return configureStore(rootReducer, rootSaga)
}
```

App.js

```
const store = createStore()

class App extends Component {
  render () {
    console.disableYellowBox = true
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <RootContainer />
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

And I got an error of

> Cannot listen for a key that isn't associated with a Redux store. First call `createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware` so that we know when to trigger your listener

I hope someone can help me and please let me know if you needed more information

Thanks

Comment: How could I addListener for ‘didFocus’ ehen integrating navigation with redux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is clearly mentioned in the `react-navigation` docs that the **`Note: createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware must be run before createReduxBoundAddListener`**.

Whenever you do use the module after importing it, the listener is being called before the store is initialized.

So the simple fix is put the `addListener` in the `ReduxNavigation` function as

```
// here is our redux-aware our smart component
function ReduxNavigation (props) {
  const addListener = createReduxBoundAddListener('root')
  const { dispatch, nav } = props
  const navigation = ReactNavigation.addNavigationHelpers({
    dispatch,
    state: nav,
    uriPrefix: prefix,
    addListener
 })
 return <AppNavigation navigation={navigation} />
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({ nav: state.nav })
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ReduxNavigation)
```

or you may make a wrapper class to the current class and bind the store to it as here

```
class RootContainer extends Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff'}}>
              <StatusBar translucent barStyle='dark-content' backgroundColor='#fff' />
              <ReduxNavigation/>
            </View>
        )
    }
}




 class App extends Component {
  render () {
    console.disableYellowBox = true
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <RootContainer />
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

I have made a sample starter kit for the same.Please checkout the link below

[**Sample Starter Kit**](https://github.com/pritishvaidya/create-react-native-redux-app)

Answer (score 1):

For those who struggle with it, be sure the import class in your App.js are first

`import configureStore from '../Redux/configureStore'`

(where you configure your Navigation Middleware)
and second or after:

`import ReduxNavigation from '../Navigation/ReduxNavigation'`

(where you call *createReduxBoundAddListener* )

Otherwise you'll keep having this message